# How are Django persistent connections(CONN_MAX_AGE) distributed?

Tags: python, django, oracle, connection-pooling

As I understand Django has persistent connections to DB as many as `CONN_MAX_AGE` represent.

If so, what is the rule to distribute the connection to an app?

For example.

case 1. The connections are distributed every time an app requests regardless of multi-process, multi-thread environment.(e.g. In async environment, each request can have a connection)

case 2. The connections are distributed to each thread(thread level)

case 3. The connections are distributed to each process(process level)

And is there any way to monitor this behavior?,

is there any pre-setting in DB to facilate DB conntion pool in `Django`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ConnectionHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, databases=None):
        """
        databases is an optional dictionary of database definitions (structured
        like settings.DATABASES).
        """
        self._databases = databases
        self._connections = local()
```

Connection is a thread local.

Note that from a DB perspective, sharing a connection between multiple threads is almost always not recommended.

And of course, no non-persistent data is shared among processes.

For a connection pool, you will need some proxy between django and the DB. But if you use persistent connections, you can achieve similar effect with multiple threads in wsgi, which will hold multiple connections to the DB.

Comment: So even if  there are two persistent connections and one thread is blocked while requesting to the DB, the other one can run a DB request using the other persistent connection in parallel. right ?

Comment: Yes. Even if one thread is blocked, the other thread has another working connection (assuming the DB is OK).